# CListCtrl grid line width

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

How to change CListCtrl grid line width? 
I am trying to understand - whether it possible in accordance with standard gridlines or should I draw it myself?

Answer (score 0):

The gridlines can't be changed.

I use the custom draw feature to accomplish this.